# Intellij IDEA format JavaDoc

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javadoc

How can I format the `return` statement so that it also aligns to the same level as the parameter description (see the image below)
[image]

I'd like to have the second line of the `return` statement at least aligned to the first line, in this particular case the word `needed` should be aligned to the word `Some`. I tried **all** settings in `Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> Java -> Tab "JavaDoc"` but did not find any setting for `return`. This is the snippet of desired output:

```
/**
 * Add 2 to x and multiplies the result with y.
 *
 * @param x X param.
 * @param y Y param
 *
 * @return Some very long return description of the return statement even if it sometimes does not make sense but is
 *         needed to show the purpose of my question.
```

As you can see "needed" is exactly below "Some".

Comment: paste the code with the desired format please.... I dont get exactly how it must look like

Comment: I think the idea is that, most of the time, the return value description should be short. More details about it should be in the method description. On the rare occasion where you have a multi-line return description, you can indent the subsequent lines manually.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems like IntelliJ *does not* have the customisation option to specify the indentation style for the description of the `@return` tag. However, this link shows that the issue has been identified in IntelliJ and is [listed as a feature to be implemented in their backlog](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-121723). A note from one of the developers:

> ***Yaroslav Lepenkin  14 Jul 2016, 03:12*** - currently it is not in the priority 
>   list, but I think I'll come up with some enhancements in 2016.3

It was raised as an issue in 2014 and the issue status recently changed from "To be discussed" to "Open", so hopefully it will be implemented in one of the next releases.

For now, although this is not the best solution, you can just tab indent each line of the description and use Ctrl + Alt + L to adjust the comment wrapping.

Comment: Lol, 5 years later it's still open

Comment: Must be low priority, but still... I'd expect more for a paid product.